# What's the alogorithm used to show places names in Cartography when zooming?

Tags: google-maps

Actually I am using graphs with Viz.js . For large graphs I want to implement the same algorithm of maps used when zooming. So, at first we get a general map then on zooming showing new places (for graph at the beginning show general nodes and on zooming show children nodes). I couldn't find the algorithm used in cartography to show/hide when zooming in/out. Can you explain to me how it works?

Comment: Categorizing your nodes and rendering conditionally depending on the zoom factor it everything you need. If your zoom factor is a number from range 1-20, you can display the general nodes let's say only when it is greater than 15, when it's 15 or lesser but greater than 10 display another group. Just on every scroll event you have to hide node groups that don't suppose to be displayed, and turn on the visibility for certain groups.